# c++ reference book stack example inefficient?

Tags: c

I'm reading through the book C++ reference by Herbert Schildt and there is a stack example in the c section of the book similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 50

void push(int i);
int pop(void);

int *tos, *p, stack[SIZE];

int main(void) {
    tos = stack;
    p = stack;
    // push, pop, etc
    return 0;
}
void push(int i) {
    p++;
    if (p==(tos+SIZE)) {
        printf("Stack overflow");
        exit(1);
    }
    *p = i; 
}
int pop(void) {
    if (p==tos) {
        printf("Stack Underflow");
        exit(1);
    }
    p--;
    return *(p+1);
}
```

The above stack implementation does not use the TOS for storing a value.  The first value is stored at TOS+1.  I couldn't see why you would do that as it seems to waste a memory space.

I have rewritten it to the example below, which doesn't waste the space (EDIT: read the selected answer - the code below is suspect!):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

void push(int i);
int pop(void);

int *tos, *p, stack[SIZE];

int main(void) {
    tos = stack;
    p = stack;
    // push, pop, etc
    return 0;
}
void push(int i) {
    if (p==(tos+SIZE)) {
        printf("Stack overflow");
        exit(1);
    }
    *p = i; 
    p++;
}
int pop(void) {
    p--;
    if (p<tos) {
        printf("Stack Underflow");
        exit(1);
    }
    return *p;
}
```

Is there a reason for Schildt's implementation not using the TOS position?

Many thanks.

Comment: Probably an oversight, or just not considered important. There are other oddities too - e.g. why have `tos` at all when you can just as easily refer to `stack`. There's a fairly common convention where stacks sometimes grow from the top downwards - maybe an early version did that, he decided it was unfair on newbies, and he translated a bit naively.

Comment: Herb Schildt's C Reference is notorious for errors: http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html. I don't know if the C++ series has similar issues.

Comment: @Scott - technically I don't think there *is* a C++ series - there's a C/C++ series (I have a copy of the second edition, copyright page says 2000). I've just done the pick-random-pages thing and I see `cout` used with no `endl` everywhere - a sure sign of naive translation from the `printf` without `\n` in the C versions that you link mentions. It's not a book I actually use, just one I bought because it was there.

Comment: @Scott - sorry, I'm wrong - he has written several C++-specific books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original code, though it exhibits poor style, has well-defined behavior. Your modified code's behavior is undefined.

To test whether the stack is empty, you need to do the pointer comparison *before* modifying the pointer. If the comparison indicates that the stack is empty, *do not decrement the pointer*.

If `p` points to `stack[0]`, then `p--;` has undefined behavior, even if you never dereference `p` after that. You cannot legally form a pointer that points before the beginning of an array, or more than one element past the end of it. (You can legally form a pointer just past the end of an array, but you can't dereference it.)

It's likely to "work" in most stack-based implementations -- which just means that this is a bug that's difficult to find through testing.

A problem in the original code: `tos` initially points to element 0 of `stack`, and it's not modified by either `push()` or `pop`(). Why isn't it declared `const`, why is it called `tos` (a name that implies "top of stack", but that's what `p` is used for), and why have that variable at all, given that `stack` or `&stack[0]` gives you the same value? I doubt that there are any *good* answers to these questions.

Also in the original code, `exit(1);` is not a portable way to signal failure (there are systems on which it signal success). `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` is the right way to do that, unless you're writing deliberately non-portable code. (Which can make sense if you're writing a program to be used only on Unix-like systems, but not if you're writing examples for a language tutorial).

My advice: Google "Schildt" to learn about the author's exceedingly poor reputation as an author of C and C++ books, and then find a book written by someone who actually understand the language.

(A previous version of this answer incorrectly blamed Schildt for some errors that were not his; my apologies for that. I still recommend avoiding his books.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he's trying to keep p always pointing somewhere within the stack, rather than pointing at some random location in memory before the stack like yours does.  As long as the invalid p isn't dereferenced anywhere (i.e. since you're calling exit if it is wrong) there shouldn't be much difference.

Comment: I'm not sure if pointing a pointer one element before the start of an array is valid. One after the end is, but C can be quite picky about these things.

Comment: @larsman - I'm pretty sure it's technically undefined behaviour. For example, on some platforms there's a chance your array might start at address 0 (and NULL wouldn't be zero). But all that's needed to fix it is checking if the stack is empty before decrementing the stack pointer for the `pop`.

Comment: @Steve314: Strictly speaking, no example is needed to demonstrate that the behavior is undefined. The language standard says the behavior is undefined, or just doesn't define the behavior. You make a good point about the rationale for the behavior's undefinedness, but there are other possible reasons. For example, an array's starting address might be at the beginning of a segment.

Comment: Regardless of the original reasons for a behavior to be undefined, once it is written as undefined in the standard, compilers start aggressively optimizing based on the undefinedness and the original reason does not matter any more. http://lwn.net/Articles/278137/

Comment: @Keith, Pascal - Human memory works better with context and explanations. Random unexplained facts get instantly forgotten, and "because the standard says so" is really no better than unexplained. Of course once the standard says something, it doesn't matter whether you have a platform where the original reasons were valid or not but still - that's a good point to make - but I feel as if you think I've committed a terrible crime by trying to make it a bit easier for people to remember the issue.

Comment: @Steve314: I certainly hope I didn't imply that you've committed a "terrible crime". In some cases, behavior is left undefined just because it wasn't worth the effort to define it, not necessarily because some specific bad thing is likely to happen. And your example was complete -- as was mine (a compiler is free to *assume* that a program doesn't do anything undefined, and to optimize the generated code accordingly). BTW, you can only notify one person for each comment; if you want Pascal to see a notification in his inbox, you'll need to include an at-sign followed by "Pascal".